# Accessing DLL pointers through Java

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I am using Java (JNA) to access DLL code. Here is the DLL I am using:

```
U32 ReadMemU32(U32 Addr, U32 NumItems, U32* pData, U8* pStatus);
```

Here is my sample code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.*;
import com.sun.jna.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.sun.jna.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class DLL1 {

    @UserFunction(Description="DLL1 Java wrapper", Name = "DLL1")
    public static String DLL1(
        @UserFunction.Arg(Name = "Address", Description = "Register Address")
        String Address
    ) throws Exception {

        byte Status[] = new byte[1];
        PointerByReference Data = new PointerByReference ();

        long Addr = Long.parseLong(Address.substring(2, Address.length()));
        DllInterface.INSTANCE.ReadMemU32(Addr, 1, Data, Status);
        System.out.println("Data = " + Data);
        System.out.println("Data.getValue() = " + Data.getValue()); 

        return null;
    }

    // C++ function definition and tell which DLL to fetch
    public interface DllInterface extends Library {

        DllInterface INSTANCE = (DllInterface) Native.loadLibrary("<dll name>", DllInterface.class);

        long ReadMemU32(long Addr, long NumItems, PointerByReference pData, byte[] pStatus);
    }
}
```

The result I am getting is:

```
Data = allocated@0xe25ac90 (8 bytes)(com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference@e25ac90)
Data.getValue() = native@0xaaaaaaaa
```

The result (0xaaaaaaaa) does not match with what I expect it to be.

I am new to Java and I am not sure if `PointerByReference` is the correct thing to use for `U32* pData`. Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the type definition for the function, I would make an educated guess and say that `pData` is the array pointer to which the function writes the read memory. You can use `int[]` directly here. Since the status is returned as an out parameter via pointer, you can use a `ByteByReference`.

In Java, `long` refers to a 64-bit integer, equivalent to C++'s `long long`. Since the type is `U32`, it's probably safe to guess that it refers to a 32-bit integer. This would be an `int`. You can check JNA's type mappings [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/e0d5537521febbc9fd92243e18e64ffc66774e01/www/Mappings.md).

Notice also that since the function accepts a 32-bit integer for the address, you cannot pass 64-bit addresses to the function.

I would guess that one proper mapping for this function would be:

```
int ReadMemU32(
    int address,
    int numItems,
    int[] pData,
    ByteByReference status
);
```

If your function truly only needs to read one 32-bit integer from memory, you can change `pData`'s type to `IntByReference` and use it in the same way as the `status` parameter's `ByteByReference`.

Since the function returns an integer, I would guess that it returns the amount of bytes read. If so, it's important to check that this value matches with what you're expecting. Check what the library's documentation says about the return value and error states.

Try this:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.*;

public class DLL1 {

    @UserFunction(Description="DLL1 Java wrapper", Name = "DLL1")
    public static String DLL1(
        @UserFunction.Arg(Name = "Address", Description = "Register Address")
        String Address
    ) throws Exception {

        String addressWithoutPrefix = Address.substring(2)
        int parsedAddress = Integer.parseInt(addressWithoutPrefix, 16)

        int bytesToRead = 1;
        int[] buffer = new int[bytesToRead];

        ByteByReference status = new ByteByReference(0);

        int BytesRead = DllInterface.INSTANCE.ReadMemU32(
            parsedAddress,
            bytesToRead,
            buffer,
            status
        );

        System.out.println("Status = " + status.getValue());
        System.out.println("Bytes read = " + bytesRead);
        System.out.println("Data = " + Arrays.toString(buffer));

        return null;
    }

    // C++ function definition and tell which DLL to fetch
    public interface DllInterface extends Library {

        DllInterface INSTANCE = (DllInterface) Native.loadLibrary("<dll name>", DllInterface.class);

        int ReadMemU32(
            int address,
            int numItems,
            int[] pData,
            ByteByReference status
        );
    }
}
```